# Optimally querying a database of ratings?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a table of ratings that stores a user ID, object ID, and a score (+1 or -1). Now, when I want to display a list of objects with their total scores, the number of +1 votes, and the number of -1 votes.

How can I do this efficiently without having to do SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rating WHERE (score = +/-1 AND object_id = ..)? That's two queries per object displayed, which is unacceptable. Is the database design reasonable?

Comment: In order to judge the design, we would need some requirements for the design. For the simple task at hand the design is fine, because there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it doesn't address your question of reasonable design,  here's a query that gets you both counts at once:

```
select
    sum(case when score = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 'positive'
,   sum(case when score = -1 then 1 else 0 end) 'negative'
,   objectId
from
    ratings
where
    objectId = @objectId ...
group by
    objectId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select object_id, 
       sum(case when score = 1 then 1 else 0) upvotes, 
       sum(case when score = -1 then -1 else 0) downvotes,
       sum(score)
from ratings
group by object_id
```

Perhaps something like that.

Comment: (You need object_id in the select too.)

Comment: (Why that is does. Thank you, kind sir. This has been edited. The correct answer to this question got it correct first time, and 48 seconds faster than myself, if I recall correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    UserID, ObjectID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN score=1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as UpVotes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN score=-1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as DownVotes,
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY UserID, ObjectID
```